# Plotly python: force axis limits (range)

Tags: python, plot, plotly

[Documentation of plotly](https://plot.ly/python/axes/#setting-the-range-of-axes-manually) says, with parameter `range` we can set the limits of the axis, for example `range = [0, 10]` sets the axis minimum to 0 and maximum to 10. According to docs, it can be used under figure, layout, scene or xaxis. Indeed `Scatter` and `Layout` accepts `xaxis` and `yaxis` arguments, which are either dicts or `plotly.graph_objs.XAxis` objects, and there it is possible to supply a `range` value. However, with trying all the variations I can imagine, it apparently fails to set the limits. In addition, the first subplot appears to be below the others. See the minimum working example below, which can be run in any Jupyter notebook.

Bonus question: why `fill` argument at `Scatter` fails to set the fill color of the dots?

```
import plotly
import plotly.tools
import plotly.graph_objs
plotly.offline.init_notebook_mode()

data = {
    'A': {
        'x': [1.0, 2.0, 6.0, 8.0],
        'y': [34.0, 36.0, 38.0, 40.0],
        's': [0.00416, 0.01125, 0.0038, 0.002]
    },
    'B': {
        'x': [1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 2.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 2.0, 2.0, 3.0,
            4.0, 2.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 7.0],
        'y': [30.0, 32.0, 32.0, 33.0, 34.0, 34.0, 34.0, 35.0,
            36.0, 36.0, 36.0, 38.0, 38.0, 38.0, 38.0, 38.0, 40.0],
        's': [0.029999999999999999, 0.19625000000000001, 0.070833333333333331,
            0.0079166666666666673, 0.23749999999999999, 0.37708333333333333,
            0.028333333333333332, 0.018749999999999999, 0.51875000000000004,
            0.066666666666666666, 0.02375, 0.0066666666666666671,
            0.012083333333333333, 0.01125, 0.016666666666666666,
            0.0058333333333333336, 0.0275]
    },
    'C': {
        'x': [1.0, 2.0, 1.0, 2.0, 2.0],
        'y': [32.0, 32.0, 34.0, 34.0, 36.0],
        's': [0.029208333333333333, 0.0050000000000000001, 0.03820833333333333,
            0.022833333333333334, 0.029083333333333333],
    },
    'D': {
        'x': [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 1.0, 2.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 1.0, 1.0,
            2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 6.0, 7.0],
        'y': [30.0, 30.0, 31.0, 31.0, 32.0, 32.0, 33.0, 33.0, 34.0, 34.0, 34.0,
            35.0, 36.0, 36.0, 36.0, 36.0, 36.0, 36.0, 38.0, 38.0, 38.0, 38.0,
            38.0, 40.0, 40.0],
        's': [0.0087500000000000008, 0.050000000000000003, 0.008750000000000000,
            0.013333333333333334, 0.60875000000000001, 0.16666666666666666,
            0.04583333333333333, 0.00070833333333333338, 0.73320833333333335,
            0.54541666666666666, 0.040833333333333333, 0.02, 0.0700000000000,
            0.73124999999999996, 0.1125, 0.066666666666666666, 0.02083333332,
            0.0083333333333333332, 0.027916666666666666, 0.0212500000000000,
            0.070833333333333331, 0.11666666666666667, 0.040833333333333333,
            0.059999999999999998, 0.1125]
    }
}

xlim = [0, 9]
ylim = [13, 60]

traces = []

for name in sorted(data.keys()):
    sub = data[name]

    traces.append(plotly.graph_objs.Scatter(x = sub['x'], y = sub['y'],
                                        mode = 'markers',
                                        marker = dict(
                                            size = sub['s'],
                                            sizemode = 'area',
                                            sizeref = 0.0001),
                                        name = name,
                                        fill = '#333333',
                                        showlegend = False,
                                        xaxis = dict(range = xlim),
                                        yaxis = dict(range = ylim))
                                    )

fig = plotly.tools.make_subplots(rows=2,
                                cols=2,
                                subplot_titles=sorted(data.keys())
                            )

for i, trace in enumerate(traces):
    fig.append_trace(trace, row = i // 2 + 1, col = (i % 2) + 1)

fig['layout'].update(height = 1000, width = 600, title = main_title,
                    xaxis = dict(range = xlim), yaxis = dict(range = ylim))

plotly.offline.iplot(fig, show_link = False)
```

Result looks like this:

[image: failed to set axes limits]

Comment: You might get a better chance of answering your question on the Plotly Forum https://community.plot.ly

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like it's working as expected in `plotly=5.1.0`.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots

fig = make_subplots(rows=2, cols=2, subplot_titles=sorted(data.keys()))
for i, name in enumerate(sorted(data.keys())):
    sub = data[name]
    fig.add_trace(
        go.Scatter(
            x = sub['x'], 
            y = sub['y'],
            mode = 'markers',
            marker = dict(
                size = sub['s'],
                sizemode = 'area',
                sizeref = 0.0001,
            ),
            name = name,
            showlegend = False,
        ),
        row = i // 2 + 1,
        col = (i % 2) + 1,        
    )
fig.update_xaxes(range=[0, 9])
fig.update_yaxes(range=[13, 60])  
fig
```

[image: scatter grid]